# Use data from Underscore.js with a Flot.js stacked bar graph

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, flot

I have the following Javascript inside my Twig file that creates an initial array, which Underscore.js then groups by Month and then by WT. What I want to do is take the data from Underscore.js and pass it through to Flot.js in order to make a Stacked Bar Chart with each bar corresponding to a month, and the bar is then made up of different values of WT.

```
    init.push(function () {

        var Co2Data = [
        {% for c2 in co2Output %}
            {WT: '{{c2.wasteType}}', Month: '{{c2.completionDate}}', Weight:'{{c2.co2Saving}}'},
        {% endfor %}
        ]

        var groupedData = _.chain(Co2Data)
            .groupBy('Month')
            .map(function (group, key) {
            return {
                Month: key,
                WTs: _.chain(group)
                    .groupBy("WT")
                    .map(function (group, key) {
                    return {
                        WT: key,
                        TotalWeight: _.reduce(group, function(memo, i){ 
                            return memo + parseFloat(i.Weight); 
                        }, 0)
                    };
                })
                .value()
            }})
            .value();

                    var NewCo2Data = [
                        _.each(groupedData, function(m) {
                            {label: wt.WT, data: [[m.Month, wt.TotalWeight],]}
                        });
                    ];

        // Init Chart
        $('#jq-flot-bars-2').pixelPlot(NewCo2Data, {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: .9,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            },
            xaxis: { tickDecimals: 2 },
            yaxis: { tickSize: 1000 }
        }, {
            height: 205,
            tooltipText: "y + ' visitors at ' + x + '.00h'"
        });
    });
```

However, when I load this on to my page I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>
> {label: wt.WT, data: [[m.Month, wt.TotalWeight],]}

Not sure why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't JavaScript:

```
var NewCo2Data = [
    _.each(groupedData, function(m) {
        {label: wt.WT, data: [[m.Month, wt.TotalWeight],]}
    });
];
```

You can't put a statement inside `[...]` like that nor can you use an Object literal in that context. Perhaps you really want to use [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map):

```
var NewCo2Data = _.map(groupedData, function(m) {
    return { label: wt.WT, data: [[m.Month, wt.TotalWeight]] };
});
```

`_.map` is used to transform data from one format to another, `_.each` simply iterates over a collection. You also had a stray trailing comma in the array literal, some JavaScript engines won't care about that, some will.